# How to get a list of all the databases with their extended properties?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SQL server 2008 
I want to get all the databases in the server with a specific property related to the database.
Say for example we have an extended property with key "x" for some databases in the server.
i want the result to be

```
DatabaseName | x
Db1          | value1
Db2          | value2
Db3          | value3
Db4          | null
```

where Db4 doesn't have the extended property with key "x"

any help 
Thank you very much

Comment: What is a property 'x'? Any example? The main data on databases is stored here `SELECT * FROM sys.databases`

Comment: Every database in sql server has extended properties as key value pairs
i want the extended property with key "x".

Comment: I got it! Hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.extended_properties` ([info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186989(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_1)) and dynamic SQL to get all extended properties.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#extprops') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #extprops

CREATE TABLE #extprops (
    dbname nvarchar(max),
    class_desc sql_variant,
    [name] sql_variant,
    [value] sql_variant
)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = (
    SELECT 'USE '+QUOTENAME([name])+ ' INSERT INTO #extprops SELECT ''' +[name] + ''' as dbname, class_desc, [name], [value] FROM sys.extended_properties;' +CHAR(10)
    FROM sys.databases
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT *
FROM #extprops
```

Output:

```
dbname          class_desc          name                                    value
msdb            DATABASE            Microsoft_Management_Utility_Version    ___SQLVERSION___NEW___
AdventureWorks  DATABASE            MS_Description                          AdventureWorks 2014 Sample OLTP Database
AdventureWorks  OBJECT_OR_COLUMN    MS_Description                          Check constraint [ProductLine]='r' OR [ProductLine]='m' OR [ProductLine]='t' OR [ProductLine]='s' OR [ProductLine]='R' OR [ProductLine]='M' OR [ProductLine]='T' OR [ProductLine]='S' OR [ProductLine] IS NULL
AdventureWorks  OBJECT_OR_COLUMN    MS_Description                          Stores (including store contacts) that sell Adventure Works Cycles products to consumers.
AdventureWorks  OBJECT_OR_COLUMN    MS_Description                          Manufacturing failure reasons lookup table.
AdventureWorks  OBJECT_OR_COLUMN    MS_Description                          Primary key for ScrapReason records.
AdventureWorks  OBJECT_OR_COLUMN    MS_Description                          Failure description.
...
```

If you `print @sql` you will see query like this:

```
USE [master] INSERT INTO #extprops SELECT 'master' as dbname, class_desc, [name], [value] FROM sys.extended_properties;
USE [tempdb] INSERT INTO #extprops SELECT 'tempdb' as dbname, class_desc, [name], [value] FROM sys.extended_properties;
USE [model] INSERT INTO #extprops SELECT 'model' as dbname, class_desc, [name], [value] FROM sys.extended_properties;
```

After that you can use any filters on `#extprops` table.

Comment: Thank you very much it is extremely helpful